# Find out and fix dns leaks with expressvpn

Tags: vpn, dns

So, I'm using expressvpn app on my raspberry pi 4, and sending the connection from the VPN to the ethernet port (I'm going to use it between my ISP modem and my router)

It works well, and if the VPN is disconnected, the internet stops working, as intended.
The problem is, it's using the ISP DNS servers instead of the ones supplied by the ExpressVPN app, and I can't find where are the DNS servers being resolved, because theres the expressVPN configurations, the dnsmasq configurations, which I'm pretty sure I've had to set up for sending the connection through the ethernet port and also, mdns from avahi for setting up my raspberrypi.local connection on the LAN

So I'm not sure where are the DNS servers being set up... I tried using nslookup as well, and it says my DNS servers are 127.0.0.1

How can I fix those leaks?

Comment: Since you're paying for ExpressVPN go and ask their help desk at https://www.expressvpn.com/support/. That's what you're paying for.

Comment: They sort of only support what they call setting up a "virtual router" in Windows and Mac, so, since RPi is running linux, they don't know what to do exactly

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check that your ISP is not blocking or redirecting port 53. Some ISP's force you to use their DNS servers, regardless of your modem/router DHCP or your localhost's static IP settings. See also [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1265632/can-a-isp-prevent-or-block-me-from-using-custom-dns-and-force-using-their-dns) on the Superuser SE.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, because using the APP on windows doesn't have those DNS leaks, it's only when supplying the VPN via Raspberry PI to the computer or router

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest getting a router that can run Merlin (Asus comes to mind)
You can then setup your modem/router to force VPN for all or select clients connected.

ExpressVPN has instructions on how to do this... that said I no longer use ExpressVPN.

They changed hands a few months ago, I now use MULLVAD.  Not only do I have my router sending VPN to Mullvad say... Dallas, but I force all clients to use DNS servers (Oh yeah, Merlin has option to NOT send IP with DNS or something like that (dns leak)) through PiHOLE as DNS1 and MULLVAD has their own pi hole dns type thing, that I use for DNS2 just incase my RPi is down or something (better than nothing for ads). Then on my phones I use mullvad app, and have them VPN to say Miami, or something. Bounce around as much as you can I guess... PiHOLE you can have use DNS from COMODO, MULLVAD, etc aswell. Mix it up :)